# Difference between bitshifting mask vs unsigned int

Tags: c++, c

For a project, I had to find the individual 8-bits of a unsigned int. I first tried bit-shifting the mask to find the numbers, but that didn't work, so I tried bit-shifting the value and it worked.

What's the difference between these two? Why didn't the first one work?

```cpp
ExampleFunk(unsigned int value){
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ExampleSubFunk(value & (0x00FF << (i * 8)));
  }
}
```

```cpp
ExampleFunk(unsigned int value){
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ExampleSubFunk((value >> (i * 8)) & 0x00FF);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give the input and expected result? "Funk" is not exactly a good description of what the function is meant to do. The function doesn't return anything or set any value to be returned so it is a bit unclear what it is supposed to do.

Comment: When you shift the mask, it finds the byte, but leaves it at its original position in the number.

Comment: 1. You should take a sheet of paper, pencil and do all the maths yourself without touching the keyboard. It would discover it yourself. Imagine when I was learning C there was no Internet, no syntax colouring editors, even no PCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the value `0xAABBCCDD` as an example.

The expression `value & (0xFF << (i * 8))` assumes the values:

```
0xAABBCCDD & 0x000000FF = 0x000000DD
0xAABBCCDD & 0x0000FF00 = 0x0000CC00
0xAABBCCDD & 0x00FF0000 = 0x00BB0000
0xAABBCCDD & 0xFF000000 = 0xAA000000
```

While the expression `(value >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF` assumes the values:

```
0xAABBCCDD & 0x000000FF = 0x000000DD
0x00AABBCC & 0x000000FF = 0x000000CC
0x0000AABB & 0x000000FF = 0x000000BB
0x000000AA & 0x000000FF = 0x000000AA
```

As you can see, the results are quite different after `i = 0`, because the first expression is only "selecting" 8 bits from `value`, while the second expression is shifting them down to the least significant byte first.

Note that in the first case, the expression `(0xFF << (i * 8))` is shifting an `int` literal (`0xFF`) left. You should cast the literal to `unsigned int` to avoid signed integer overflow, which is undefined behavior:

```
value & ((unsigned int)0xFF << (i * 8))
```

Comment: It might be more helpful to show the first set of results with all the leading zeroes.

Comment: @Barmar makes sense

Comment: "should cast the literal to unsigned int to avoid signed integer overflow" --> or use `0xFFu`

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```cpp
ExampleFunk(unsigned int value){
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ExampleSubFunk(value & (0x00FF << (i * 8)));
  }
}
```

You are shifting the bits of `0x00FF` itself, producing new masks of `0x00FF`, `0xFF00`, `0xFF0000`, and `0xFF000000`, and then you are masking `value` with each of those masks.  The result contains only the 8 bits of `value` that you are interested in, but those 8 bits are not moving position at all.

In this code:

```cpp
ExampleFunk(unsigned int value){
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ExampleSubFunk((value >> (i * 8)) & 0x00FF);
  }
}
```

You are shifting the bits of `value`, thus moving those 8 bits that you want, and then you are masking the result with `0x00FF` to extract those 8 bits.